# how to properly use jquery appear plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been using the jquery appear plugin for some time now, but it appears I have a problem.

This is how I do it at the moment.

I have a page of indefinite length. It is  a list of hidden SPANs with only the first one visible. The HTML is loaded onto these SPANs from OnAppear event handler. In that same event handler I make the next SPAN visible by setting it's style.display property.

Everything works well except when the following senario arises.

Suppose the user have been scrolling page down for some time, and accumulated quite a bit of content on it (loaded by OnAppear event handler). He picks one item and opens a detailed view, and that's a different page. After looking at the detailed view the user wants to go back to the list, and clicks the BACK button in the browser.

The browser tries to use the cached version of the page scrolled a way down.
But all the content loaded by OnAppear is missing. The user sees the bottom of very long empty page.

My question is: is there a proper pattern for using the jquery Appear plugin to handle this situation nicely ?

Ie. when the user comes back to the page through Browser's BACK button, I want the user to see a single SPAN with content loaded in it. If the user scrolls UP or down from that position on the page, the usual OnAppear processing would take place.

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest saving the position the user scrolled down to in the session or likewise and have the content react accordingly. You won't be able to influence that browser behavior, it will always try to reproduce the position the user was last at.

Comment: Of course! All I have to add is remember the last page of the result set requested from the client, and the direction we are going (up or down) on the server. Thank you for inspirational answer!

Comment: There is another problem: OnAppear is fired only once for an element. It won't fire when the user comes back to the page through BACK button.

Comment: I think you'd have to skip the OnAppear on page load entirely, once you react to information from the session. You would probably also need to purge the session at certain points in your navigation (when clicking certain links to the page in question for example), so the user has a fresh start at the top after certain clicks instead of always being forced back down to where he was when last he viewed the page. Once the page is loaded and the position was restored, just proceed loading your content with OnAppear again.